# Simple way of having horizontal scroll in html?

Tags: html, horizontal-scrolling

I've been reading other posts about having horizontal scroll, but I haven't been able to do it. I took a web design class a very long time ago at my local community college, and all that was taught was basic HTML. I haven't been up to date with the latest web technology, which is why I'm considering to stop working for a singer in Los Angeles. I have tried reading tutorials, and looking at websites and looking/importing the code into Dreamweaver to see if I can understand it, but it's been hard.

Right now I was asked to have the news as just a thumbnail, but with horizontal scrolling. Right now I have the news appear in an iframe, but scrolling with a mouse is not even possible. It's also very hard to use the finger on a mobile device. What would be the best way to have something like apple.com in a simple html page? Something like just having the dots, and moving to the next page?

This is the news page of the page I work in: http://www.maria-del-pilar.com/main.html and this is the the page that loads within the iframe: http://www.maria-del-pilar.com/news.html

What do you guys recommend I should do? What would be the easiest way to scroll horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably not want to hear this, but you will not make horizontal scrolling any better than what you have now without adding some javascript.

Great things can be achieved with jQuery - you will probably have to learn something new in order to use it, but hey - life is about learning, isn't it?

Also, after you learn just basics of jQuery, you will be able to use solution of somebody else and not necessarily write all code by yourself. Like this - http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-horizonal-scroll-demos-plugins/

You can also abandon idea of horizontal scrolling whatsoever - I don't think it is anything special in terms of usability or design anyway. But I understand that you want to achieve what you were asked for.

Good luck